Shadcn `DialogContent` requires a `DialogTitle` for the component to be accessible for screen reader users
I'm getting the following error in my JavaScript console every time I open my Shadcn Sheet component

DialogContent requires a DialogTitle for the component to be accessible for screen reader users.

I'm confused because I don't use any Dialog components in my sheet, so why is this happening and how do I fix this error? Here's my relevant code for the Sheet component:
<Sheet open={openMenu} onOpenChange={setOpenMenu}>
  <SheetTrigger asChild>
    <Button variant="ghost">
      <MenuIcon color={location.pathname === "/" ? "white" : "black"} size="2em" />
    </Button>
  </SheetTrigger>
  <SheetContent side="right" className="fixed z-50">
    <div >
      <p>Sheet Content</p>
    </div>
  </SheetContent>
</Sheet>


The Shadcn Sheet component is an extension of the Dialog component, and so <SheetContent> requires a <SheetTitle> just like a regular Dialog component requires . Just add a sheet title underneath your sheet content and the error will go away.
<SheetContent side="right">
  <SheetTitle>Menu</SheetTitle> // Add a Sheet title
</SheetContent>

If you don't want the title to show up in your application, use radixUI's VisuallyHidden component like so:
<VisuallyHidden.Root>
  <SheetTitle>
    Menu
  </SheetTitle>
</VisuallyHidden.Root>


<VisuallyHidden> also worked for me when wrapping the <SheetTitle> component as the inner child. Do you know if there's downside or upside to one way versus the other?

@JasonRStevensCFA Good question. Using  as the inner child will produce a noticeable offset to following elements, as mentioned by @Dari4sho. Having <SheetTitle> as the inner child removes this extra spacing, and is therefore the better solution. I'll update my answer

Oh that's awesome to know and thank you! I didn't put two and two together w.r.t. @Dari4sho's answer.

Notice, even with VisuallyHidden applied as suggested by @Jasperan, SheetTitle will add a noticeable offset to following elements because of the nature of the CSS box model.
To avoid that, you can simply add display: none to the SheetTitle - using tailwind:
<SheetTitle className="hidden">
  <VisuallyHidden.Root>x</VisuallyHidden.Root>
</SheetTitle>


Thanks for pointing this out. Using className="hidden" works but it also removes the component from the accessibility tree. If you use <SheetTitle> as the inner child to <VisuallyHidden> then the extra space is removed while also remaining accessible
